# how to make an object an instanceof of its own prototype's property

Tags: javascript, scope, reference, prototyping

taking a standard browser as example,

there is the Window class instantiated as window variable

window variable also contains the Window constructor (window.Window)

test this in your (standard) browser:

```
alert(window instanceof window.Window);

var asd = function(){};
asd.prototype.test = asd;
var x = new asd();
alert(x instanceof x.test);
```

now, window is also instanceof EventTarget that is stored in window.EventTarget

how to inherit EventTarget in the window object?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question, but keep in mind that `window` is special object because (a) it is the global object and (b) it is a host object, meaning it's behaviour is not entirely defined by the specification.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to programmatically do this in user-space code, with some other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering to myself :|

```
var EvtTarg = function(){};
EvtTarg.prototype.justATest = function(){alert("asd");};

var Win = function(){};
Win.prototype = Object.create(EvtTarg.prototype);
Win.prototype.EvtTarg = EvtTarg;
Win.prototype.Win = Win;

var win = new Win();
alert(win instanceof win.Win);
alert(win instanceof win.EvtTarg);
```

there is a better way to do this?